# Android emulator difficulties

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator, emulation, adt

I am coming to Android from an iOS background. I also have considerable Java experience, so I believe that transitioning shouldn't be that difficult. But it has been, for reasons beyond actual coding.

The main issue I am having is with the emulators. It seems I must reboot the emulator for every build/test that I do. At the rate I'm experiencing, this could increase my development time many times over due to the insane amount of time I spend waiting for the emulator to start. I would like to find a bare bones emulator that does not require this crazy amount of wait time. Do I really have to restart the emulator for every little test? Surely this isn't what Android developers contend with on a daily basis. I am using the ADT bundle for Mac OS.

Can anyone help me?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It seems I must reboot the emulator for every build/test that I do

Not normally. Most developers start an emulator once and run it all day. Certain scenarios (e.g., testing getting control at boot time) would require restarting the emulator.

> Do I really have to restart the emulator for every little test?

No.

> So, the emulators are considered pretty useless in Android development?

No. Particularly if you use [the x86 emulator images](http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html#accel-vm), the emulator is faster than hardware.

> If I use a physical device, does that allow the use of breakpoints, etc, as if I were using a standard debugger?

Generally speaking, yes. And on OS X, it should work for any device that has the "Allow USB debugging" option in Settings (precise location varies a bit by OS version and, possibly, device). Windows gets a bit dicier, insofar as you need device-specific drivers, which may or may not exist.

Comment: Thanks for the input. Sorry to echo my frustrations, but I'm really disappointed that the ADT Bundle advertises itself as a no-issue, up and running package. I've been unsuccessful at getting it to run on Win or Mac. On the Mac, I can run an app in the emulator once, then future build/test attempts simply hang on the emulator. I'm not understanding why Android is getting so much market share.

Comment: As an alternative to the ADT emulator, try bluestacks (http://www.bluestacks.com/). Works fine for development/debugging, at least on Windows. But frankly, I'd suggest developing straight on the physical device, more than on if possible.

Comment: @PhilTownsend: "I've been unsuccessful at getting it to run on Win or Mac" -- conversely, while I have not used the bundle on the Mac, I have had no problems with students setting up the bundle on a wide range of Windows machines over the past few months.

Answer (score 0):

It is a lot easier to develop on a physical device over USB, but if this is not available to you, then the emulator is your only option, and I do not know of any other emulators apart from the one that you are using.

The emulator should not require a restart when making changes to your application, but to be sure that the changes take effect you may need to run

```
adb uninstall com.example.yourapp.main
```

from a command-line, substituting your app's identifier, to be sure that the installed one is removed and the new one will take its place.

Comment: So, the emulators are considered pretty useless in Android development?

Comment: If I use a physical device, does that allow the use of breakpoints, etc, as if I were using a standard debugger?

Comment: Yes, a device lets you use breakpoints. And, unfortunately - especially with recent Android targets, emulators are very inconvenient.